# How do I persist a Facebook instance in multiple IOS view classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk, protocols

I've been a reader of Stack Overflow for quite a while now and am looking forward to participating!  On to the question...

I've been programming for about 10 years, but am brand new to iOS programming & Objective-C.

I am trying to build an application that requires Facebook login.  When the application opens it needs to load a view with a logo and a Facebook login button.  I can do that and make it work with no problem.  After they log in with Facebook, my application will send an API call to my server and authenticate them with my system and send back a callback with their system permissions.  If it comes back that they have the correct permissions to advance, they will get sent to a view with a tabbed interface.  I also have the tabbed interface working.

I made a FirstViewController to handle the Facebook login button, and have view controllers for each tab.

In the MyAppDelegate.m file will exist something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    //init facebook & send initial view with login button
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"MYAPPID"];
    [self.window addSubview:FirstViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //Code to check permissions from webserver
    if (permissions && _isLoggedIn) {
    // Add the tab bar controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else //access denied view
    return YES;
}
```

Now, I need to make the call to the Facebook login method in FirstViewController...

```
[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
```

1)  How do I access it the Facebook instance in MyAppDelegate? (I need to be able to access from all other views also.) Do I create a delegate/protocol to access it from MyAppDelegate?

2)  Am I doing this an incredibly idiotic way?  If so, please help an amateur iOS programmer get on the right path.

3)  How can I utilize the "delegate:" argument in the Facebook method well?  I'm not sure I understand it very well.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the Facebook Objective-C API, but I can give you some insight into setting up global access to your Facebook instance. You can get to the app delegate like so:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

As long as you have a public method for accessing the `facebook` ivar/property of `MyAppDelegate`, you can get to it like so:

```
Facebook *theFacebook = [appDelegate facebook];
```

This won't give you any warnings as long as you `#import "MyAppDelegate.h"` somewhere.

As for `-authorize:delegate:`, take a look at [Facebook.h](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Facebook.h). The delegate object you pass to that method should implement the `FBSessionDelegate` protocol.

For more on delegation in general, check out [Apple's documentation on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

**Edit**

To be really explicit here, this is what you should put in your `MyAppDelegate.h` file:

```
// MyAppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Facebook;

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    Facebook *facebook;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

@end
```

And `MyAppDelegate.m`

```
// MyAppDelegate.m

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
#import "Facebook.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBarController;
@synthesize facebook;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    /*...your implementation here...*/
}

/*...more methods...*/

@end
```

Comment: Regarding the answer to my first question... I just can't get it to work.  I'm getting an error "No '-facebook' method found" on the line "[appDelegate facebook];"  I'm quite confused as to why it is not working.

Comment: You need to add a `-facebook` method to your app delegate class's header file and include that header file wherever you access the `Facebook` instance.

Comment: I had all of the things that you posted just fine.  My issue was circular dependencies.  I threw @class before my #import's and ended up OK.  I'm having an issue with a NIB file properly loading now, but at least I can access the Facebook object in my MyAppDelegate.  Thanks.