# How can I use Facebook instance in a ViewController?

Tags: ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having troubles developing an iOS 5 App with Facebook SDK integration.
My App has many ViewsController and for each of them I want to get different data from Facebook using different requests (of course).
At the moment I can get data only on the AppDelegate (following the official tutorial) but I need to get data in the view controller.
I tried 2 option: 
1) Instantiate different Facebook instances on each ViewController 
-It dosent' work, I don't know why but it seems that

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;`
is never called

2 Instantiate the Facebook instance in the AppDelegate and then use that instance in ViewControllers
- It don't works because with this code (found here: [How do I persist a Facebook instance in multiple IOS view classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454857/how-do-i-persist-a-facebook-instance-in-multiple-ios-view-classes))

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Facebook *facebook = [appDelegate facebook];
}
```

facebook is nil.

Which is the proper way to work?

Comment: Ciao! Where did you implement - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation; ?

Comment: In the viewcontroller because it needs to access to the Facebook instance in the implementation

Comment: look at my answer, let me know if you find that something is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I will edit my answer if you give me after that more feedback.)

I haven't used a lot the Facebook SDK but I remember having that problem when I tried.

The `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` implementation should be in your app delegate

If you need to access your Facebook instance in just one viewController (let's say MyFacebooViewController)

You can have something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface MyFacebookViewController : UIViewController <FBSessonDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook *facebook;
...
@end
```

And your .m file should contain this

```
#import "MyFacebookViewController.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyFacebookViewController

@synthesize facebook = _facebook;

-(Facebook *)facebook
{
    if(!_facebook){
        _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:MY_APP_ID andDelegate:self];
    }
    return _facebook;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ((MyAppDelegate *)([[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])).facebookViewController = self;
    ...
}
```

And of course you need to implement your FBSessionDelegate and FBRequestDelegate methods

In the AppDelegate :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyFacebookViewController.h"

@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyFacebookConnectViewController *facebookViewController;
@end
```

And it's in the implementation file that you need to put the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize facebookViewController = _facebookViewController;
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [self.facebookViewController.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

If you still have problems let me know!

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! 
What should I do if I want to use the same Facebook instance in another ViewController?

Comment: I posted another answer showing how to access the same Facebook instance in your app. I haven't tested it so let me know if there's something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not editing my answer as this is code I've never tested.

If you want to use the same Facebook instance in different viewController this is one way to do it:

As already mentioned in your question, you should initialize it in the appDelegate (I would use a property.)

MyAppDelegate.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
@end
```

MyAppDelegate.m :

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize facebook = _facebook;

-(Facebook *)facebook
{
    if(!_facebook){
        _facebook = [Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:MY_APP_ID andDelegate:self];
    }
    return _facebook;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Then in any ViewController that you would want you could have a Facebook property that you would not alloc/init but you would ask it from the appDelegate this way

AnyViewController.h :

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

@interface AnyViewController : UIViewController
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) Facebook *facebook;
@end
```

AnyViewController.m :

```
#import "AnyViewController.h"

@implementation AnyViewController

@synthesize facebook = _facebook;

-(Facebook *)facebook
{
    if(!_facebook){
        MyAppDelegate *theAppDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _facebook = theAppDelegate.facebook;
    }
    return _facebook;
}
```

And of course the different ViewControllers you'll be using should implement the different SDK protocols depending on your needs

You should have a look at the sample project by Facebook that's called [Hackbook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook)